# What game is this character on Nintendo's eShop from?

Tags: game-identification

I've been planning to buy a 3DS and was exploring Nintendo's eShop online and I ran across one of the buttons advertising games with DLC and it has a character that I have never seen before?

Does anyone know what game this character is from and who it is?

And before anyone asks I cannot reverse image search the image because it isn't technically a picture on Nintendo's Website.

[image]

Comment: Just as a side-note, the image doesn't need to be on a specific website to use the search-by-image feature of Google.  For example, [this search](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&q=https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5eU3.jpg) using your image's URL leads to search by image link, which leads to wikis and various other websites.  You can also upload images directly into the search-by-image tool.

Comment: The question title is fairly vague. You may want to mention the image is from the Nintendo e-shop.

Comment: My first sentence in this question already said that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That appears to be a reskin of [Agitha from Twilight Princess](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Agitha).

Here is what she normally looks like:

[image: Agitha]

The reason that image is the image representing DLC is that that particular skin is part of the Link's Awakening DLC pack for [Hyrule Warriors Legends](http://koei.wikia.com/wiki/Agitha).

Comment: The linked page mentions the specific image is "Crazy Tracy" from the Link's Awakening pack.

Comment: @Joe which one?

Comment: The latter link towards the bottom.

Comment: The character herself is not part of the DLC; she comes with the game.  Her "Crazy Tracy" skin (where she is recolored to look like a character from Link's Awakening) is what is DLC.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann ah, okay. Edited for accuracy.